# Android choose an image for button to be enabled

Tags: android, button, bitmap

I have a button, and I want it to be enabled only when the user has choosen an image
I made this code, but it doesn't work :(

```
Code updated
```

Help please ..

the user can get an image by selecting one from the gallery, or capturing one .. if that is related

UPDATE::

these are my camera and gallery code

```
    btnGallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            btnNext.setEnabled(true);
        }
    });

    btnCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
            startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            btnNext.setEnabled(true);
        }
    });
```

and this is the next button code

```
    btnNext.setEnabled(false);
    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {      
            MpClick.start();
            if (btnNext.isEnabled() == false)
            { 
                   Toast.makeText(StartActivity.this,
                            "Please get an image first.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
            }
            else
            {
                Intent next = new Intent(StartActivity.this, Option.class);
                startActivity(next);
            }
        }
        });
}
```

sometimes it takes u to the Option activity and sometimes it doesn't, and the message never shows ..
I want the message shows when u click on the next button and u didn't choose an image

but if u choose an image it'll take u to the Option activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems here:

1. You are closing your `if` statements with `;`... don't do this.
2. You are checking `setEnabled` instead of `isEnabled`.
3. You are not surrounding your conditions with `()`.
4. You don't need to check `else if`, since you're only checking the opposite of the first conditional. `else` will do just fine here.

You should instead be using:

```
    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {               
        if (btnNext.isEnabled() == false)
        { 
               Toast.makeText(StartActivity.this,
                        "Please get an image first.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
        }
        else
        {
            Intent next = new Intent(Main.this, Editing.class);
            startActivity(next);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would guess that the reason the message never shows is because `onClick` isn't called if the `Button` isn't enabled. You would have to use an `OnTouchListener` or similar if you absolutely had to show a message.

Comment: I did, now the text appears and it don't take u as I wanted it
but when u choose an image still it just shows the text that u need to select an image, it doesn't take u

Comment: Then it would seem the `Button` is never enabled. You can see it in the app--does the "next" `Button` change aesthetically when you hit the "camera" or "gallery" buttons?

Comment: You should probably start a new question for this (again with your pertinent code). Debugging and sharing code through comments is basically impossible.

Answer (score 1):

```
 btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {               
            if (!btnNext.isEnabled())
            { 
                   Toast.makeText(StartActivity.this,
                            "Please get an image first.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
            }
            else
            {
                Intent next = new Intent(Main.this, Editing.class);
                startActivity(next);
            }
        }
      });
```

Comment: it didn't work , it takes u to the editing activity either way, and doesn't show a toast message

Answer (score 1):

use **if(btnNext.setEnabled(false))** instead of if **btnNext.setEnabled(false);**

and use **else if(btnNext.setEnabled(true))** instead of **else if btnNext.setEnabled(true);**